# How to perform economy size bidiagonal factorization using Lapack?

Tags: lapack

I want to perform an economy size bidiagonal factorization over an m x n matrix *A (m<=n)*

such that:

```
A=QBP'
```

where B is a bidiagonal matrix of size m x m, and Q, P are orthogonal matrices.

Currently, I use the following two Lapack functions to do the job:

```
dgebrd(&m,&n,x,&m,d,e,tauq,taup,work,&lwork,&info);
dorgbr(&qp,&m,&m,&n,x,&m,tauq,work,&lwork,&info);
```

From these I can get the factorization:

```
A=USV'
```

where S is bidiagonal matrix of size m x n.

I can truncate the matrices S and V to get correct B and P. However this is not optimal in terms of speed. From my test, this method is even slower than performing an economy size SVD.

Which function should I use or how to use them so that I can directly get the economy size result?

Thanks in advance.